# RichTextBox assigning new lines but only last line showing

Tags: c#, .net, concatenation, variable-assignment, richtextbox

I'm doing on a GUI to extract position X and Y from GCode by using Regex and print it on richTextBox.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextReader read = new System.IO.StringReader(richTextBox1.Text);
            int rows = richTextBox1.Lines.Length;
            Console.WriteLine(rows);
            string[] text = new string[rows];
            for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
            {
                text[r] = read.ReadLine();
                if (text[r] != null)
                {
                    Match posX = Regex.Match(text[r], @"X([0-9\.]+)");
                    Match posY = Regex.Match(text[r], @"Y([0-9\.]+)");
                    GroupCollection posXGroup = posX.Groups;
                    GroupCollection posYGroup = posY.Groups;
                    Console.WriteLine(posXGroup[1] + "\t" + posYGroup[1] + "\n");
                    richTextBox2.Text = (posXGroup[1] + "\t" + posYGroup[1] + "\n"); 
                }
            }
        }
```

My GCode:

```
N65 G2  X21.5091  Y15.5209  Z0.0000  I0.0277  J-0.7392 
N120 G2  X21.5280  Y18.0069  Z0.0000  I0.0255  J-0.7476
N210 G2  X21.5968  Y15.0534  Z0.0000  I-0.0483  J-1.2184
N230 G2  X21.6745  Y17.4894  Z0.0000  I0.0473  J-1.2560
```

My problem is printing the result to richTextBox. It prints only the value of last line: `21.6745 17.4894` but not positions in 3 lines above it. While the console prints successfully.  Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix is to concatenate the text:

```
richTextBox2.Text += (posXGroup[1] + "\t" + posYGroup[1] + "\n");
```

A better solution is never to use String Concatenation as that will put pressure on the GC as each concatenate adds to the Heap. Instead use a StringBuilder:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextReader read = new System.IO.StringReader(richTextBox1.Text);
        int rows = richTextBox1.Lines.Length;
        Console.WriteLine(rows);
        string[] text = new string[rows];
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            text[r] = read.ReadLine();
            if (text[r] != null)
            {
                Match posX = Regex.Match(text[r], @"X([0-9\.]+)");
                Match posY = Regex.Match(text[r], @"Y([0-9\.]+)");
                GroupCollection posXGroup = posX.Groups;
                GroupCollection posYGroup = posY.Groups;
                Console.WriteLine(posXGroup[1] + "\t" + posYGroup[1] + "\n");
                sb.Append(posXGroup[1]);
                sb.Append("\t");
                sb.Append(posYGroup[1]);
                sb.Append("\n"); 
            }
        }
        richTextBox2.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
```

To see why this is happening put a breakpoint on the line `richTextBox2.Text =` then step through the code pressing F10, each iteration of the loop will reset the richTextBox2.Text's value.

You're assigning over the top. You need to assign by concatenating to append the text. It doesn't matter if the text has new lines. Assignment `=` will set the  variable to the Text property. Addition assignment operator `+=` will concatenate.

Comment: Wow! Thank you a lot! In your quick fix, why we must put `+=`? I thought it automatically create a new line because I have had `"\n"` already.

Comment: See to the left of answers there is a holo tickbox, checking that and marking anwsers gives you a few rep points and lets everyone know your problem is solved. Good luck!

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: `I thought it automatically create a new line because I have had "\n" already.` No. `=` means **assign** (i.e. throw away the old content).